# Resharper rule "Function Parameter" does not accept angularjs service name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resharper

In my angularjs app all my service names start with an uppercase character. I would like to be able the allow service parameters to match the the service name, however the JavaScript "Function Parameter" name rule in Resharper does not allow parameters that start with an uppercase character.

Is it possible to configure or change the JavaScript "Function Parameter" name rule in Resharper to allow service names that start with an uppercase character?Or is there some other way to to avoid this warning?

The `BudgetingService` parameter in the following code is flagged as a warning by Resharper with the message: "Name 'BudgetingService' does not match rule 'Function Parameter'. Suggested name is 'budgetingService'."

```
app.controller('BudgetingController',
    ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', 'BudgetingService',
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, BudgetingService) {
            // ...
        }]);
```

Comment: It should be noticed that the thing you're trying to do breaks JS naming convention. Conventionally, constructor functions are PascalCase, while their instances (which a service is) are camelCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the answer you are looking for, but there is a reason for that. the only time variables in javascript should be ConstantCamelCase is when they are classes/constructors.

if anything the actual service you create should be budgetingService, not BudgetingService

just lowercase the name it's not work the fight you're trying to put up

```
app.controller('BudgetingController',
  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', 'BudgetingService',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, budgetingService) {
        budgetingService.whatever()
        // ...
    }
  ]);
```

if you REALLY want to have it uppercase, redeclare it after injecting

```
app.controller('BudgetingController',
  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', 'BudgetingService',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, budgetingService) {
        var BudgetingService = budgetingService;
        // ...
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, after reviewing the angular documentation I will change my services to camel case.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper provides a documentation to change default namings

Here is documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html